# Complete the middleware file such that, all the query parameters are validated and null and undefined values throw an error message

Tags: node.js, express

output when both name and age parameters are passed.
problem statment for creating api:
Complete the middleware file and index.js file in the given application such that, all the query parameters required by the route are validated and null and undefined values throw an error message -
The query parameters that are compulsory are - name :String, age:Number

create a route named '/query' and send response as explained above when this route is requested.
according to me the the api should include these condition to get the desired output, they are:

1.when both the query parameters are present respond with success(status:200)

2.when age query parameter is entered and name parameter is empty then respond with failure(status:403)

3.when name query parameter is entered and age parameter is empty then respond with failure(status:403)

when one of the query parameters is null for "eg: http://localhost:3000/query/?age=2&name"

```
    the output i get is this: 
    {
     "error": false,
     "status": 200,
     "userMessage": "all parameters entered",
     "data": {
     "name": "",
     "age": "2"
    }
    }
```

but the expected output should have 
          error:true,
          status:403 
this is error iam facing.

there are two files. one is  index.js file and the other checkQueryParameters.js file.(this is a middleware)

code of index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const middleware = require('./middleware/checkQueryParameter');

app.get('/query',middleware.checkQueryParameters,(req,res)=>{
res.end();
});
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Example app listening on point 
3000'));
module.exports = app;
```

code of checkQueryParameters.js

```
let checkQueryParameters = (req,res,next)=>{
  let name = req.query.name;
  let age = req.query.age;
  console.log(typeof(age));
  console.log(typeof(name))
  console.log(age);
  console.log(name);

  if(typeof name == undefined || name == null){
  let result ={
      error : true,
      status : 403,
      userMessage : 'some parameters missing',
      data : 'name'
      }
      res.send(result);
     }
     else if(typeof age == undefined || age == null){
     let result ={
         error : true,
         status : 403,
         userMessage : 'all parameters missing',
         data : 'age'
        }
        res.send(result);

     }
     else{
         let result ={
         error : false,
         status : 200,
         userMessage : 'all parameters entered',
         data :{
                 'name' : name,
                  'age' : age
               }
        }
      res.send(result);

     }
    }

   module.exports = {
      checkQueryParameters:checkQueryParameters
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is an **empty string** case.
In case of `?age=2&name`, if you `console.log(req.query.name);` you will probably see that `name` is not `null`, is not `undefined`. It is an empty string ' '. If you want to check that case as an error,  you should check for an empty string too.

```
if(typeof name == undefined || name == null || name === ''){
...
```

or

```
if(typeof age == undefined || age == null || age === ''){
....
```

And one point about the rest of your middleware logic. Inside the `if else` block, where you check about age parameter, you send a message "all parameters missing". That is wrong. `name` is not missing, the fact that age validation is executed means that your first if block was not executed, so name parameter is pretty valid. You should handle it like this:

```
if(typeof name == undefined || name == null || name === ''){
    let result = {
        error : true,
        status : 403,
        userMessage : 'name parameter is missing',
        data : 'name'
    }
    ...
} else if(typeof age == undefined || age == null || age === ''){
    let result = {
        error : true,
        status : 403,
        userMessage : 'age parameter is missing',
        data : 'age'
    }
    ...
}
else {
...
}
```